# OnChange event is not working in rzslider

Tags: angularjs

OnChange event is not triggering in rzslider.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
<div ng-repeat="info in data">
  <rzslider rz-slider-model="info.min"
            rz-slider-high="info.max"
            rz-slider-options="info.options"
            rz-slider-on-change="apply(data.id,data.type)">

            </rzslider>
</div>
</div>
```

And my function inside controller be like this

```
$scope.apply(id,type){
}
```

Min and max value is correctly updated in slider but the onchange event is not being called.

Comment: Can you add more code? such as how did you made your directive rzslider

Comment: Actually there is no directive in my solution for this slider.And slider values are initialized as follows.  let data=[];

Comment: Are you using [this slider](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider)? It seems that `onChange` should be in `options`. And your declaration of function is incorrect, should be `$scope.apply = function(id,type){}`. Do you get any error in console?

Comment: Actually there is no directive in my solution for this slider.And slider values are initialized as follows.                                                                                            let datas;                                                         
 datas=[ {name :"first",min:0,max:1,options:{floor:0,ceil:0,translate:function(value){return value;},},},                                                                                                      
{name :"second",min:0,max:1,options:{floor:0,ceil:0,translate:function(value){return value;},},}];

Comment: And yes my function is like $scope.apply=function(id,type){}